# How do I insert data from a form into multiple tables?

Tags: php, sql

How do I insert data from a form into multiple tables?  This is what I have so far :

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';
$Apple = trim($_POST['Apple']);
$Orange = trim($_POST['Orange']);
$Banana = trim($_POST['Banana']);
if (empty($Apple) && empty($Orange) && empty($Banana)){
    $error = "Please pick your fruits";
} else {
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO fruits (Apple, Orange, Banana) Values (?,?,?)");
    $insert->bind_param("sss", $Apple, $Orange, $Banana);
?>

//HTML SECTION
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Apple">Apples :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Apple" name="Apple"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Orange">Oranges:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Orange" name="Orange"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Banana">Bananas:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Banana" name="Banana"></td>
        </tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="create" name="create">CREATE</button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="btn" href="index.php">BACK</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What I would like to do is this - within the form, have another field (say tomatoes), that when the user clicks "submit", apple / orange / banana goes to the fruits table, and "tomato" goes to the "vegetables" table.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: so add a tomato field, and add a separate query to insert into the tomato table?

Comment: can I call $insert twice?  for instance, $insert=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO fruits (Apple, Orange, Banana) VALUES (?,?,?)";$insert->bindparam("sss", $Apple, $Orange, $Banana); $insert=$db->prepaire("INSERT INTO veggies (Tomato)"); $insert->bind_param("s", $Tomato);

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with, I made the mistake of misplacing the binding code for "Tomato".  One thing that I am still confused about, and am unsure about how to approach, is how I can make it to where when I click on a form field for the below example, it will populate a popup that shows current contents of the database, and allow you to copy contents of that popup(item) to the form field if needed.  Another example would be a customers and products table, you make a form field to take a customer and a product, when you click on "product" form field, it populates with all products, and allows you to click on one of the populated products to assign to that customer.

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';
$Apple = trim($_POST['Apple']);
$Orange = trim($_POST['Orange']);
$Banana = trim($_POST['Banana']);
$Tomato= trim($_POST['Tomato']);
if (empty($Apple) && empty($Orange) && empty($Banana) && empty($Tomato)){
    $error = "Please pick your fruits";
} else {
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO fruits (Apple, Orange, Banana) Values (?,?,?)");
    $insert->bind_param("sss", $Apple, $Orange, $Banana);
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO veggies(Tomato) Values (?)");
    $insert->bind_param("s", $Tomato);
?>

//HTML SECTION
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Apple">Apples :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Apple" name="Apple"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Orange">Oranges:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Orange" name="Orange"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Banana">Bananas:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Banana" name="Banana"></td>
        </tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="create" name="create">CREATE</button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="btn" href="index.php">BACK</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```